# Submit form action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do some validate before form submit.

I can not modify the html code and existing js (the only way is to add new js file).

I tried this one:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert("check");
    return false;
});
```

but it does not call.

I tried this one too:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    alert("check");
    return false;
});
```

it calls correctly but only for `alert()`.

How is it possible to set `false` for disable form submit when my `checkFunction()` returns false?

Comment: where is your HTML?

Comment: Have you tried `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: where is `checkFunction()` invoked?

Comment: @Passerby I tried to  add `e.preventDefault();` before the `alert()` but it doesnt work (form is submitted).

Comment: @Arvind the function `checkFunction()` is not called yet. It doesnt work for const values `true` and `false` (I mean that form is submited).

Comment: You could try removing any existing event handlers before adding your own, eg: `$('form').off('submit').on('submit', function() {...`

Comment: have you add multiple forms on the same page @karlperson

Comment: if you have multiple forms on the same page then give `id` to particular form

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added `.off('submi')` but it doesnt work (form is submitted anyway)

Comment: @Rudra i can not set the id to the form

Comment: how many forms you have on the same page @karlperson

Answer (score 1):

You can use **jquery validation** plugin for validation before form submit. It is better for that. You can refer below link:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault` should help you there, because it is preventing the default behavior of the submit.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("check");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: `return false` will perform the same action (as well as `stopPropagation`), so if that didn't work, this is unlikely to make a difference.

Comment: I tried it `e.preventDefault()` but it does not work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Do you have any idea what could be a solution?

Comment: @karlperson May this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted

Comment: With such little information in the question it's impossible to determine the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what kind of information is necessary to detect the problem?

Comment: An example which shows the behaviour, so we'd need to see the HTML as well as any other events which are put on the element by the external JS file.